# Provided id of the wrong type for class when testing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have got this issue when testing-
Provided id of the wrong type for class `com.myapp.ibank.domain.Customer. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String`

And I honestly cant figure out why I have got this and what is actually happening. When I use it normally, like running on a local tomcat and saving it through a controller and then service, it works just fine. No errors. This behaviour makes no sense to me.

I am using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate as a provider.

Here is test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = RootConfig.class),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)

})
@Transactional
public class AccountRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();

        Customer cus = new Customer();
        cus.setFirstName("John");
        cus.setLastName("Smith");
        customerService.save(cus);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveAccount() {

        Account account = new Account();
        account.setCustomer(customerService.findByName("John"));
        account.setName();
        account.setDebitCard(new DebitCard((long) 2000));

        accountRepository.create(account);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSavePremiumAccount() {

        PremiumAccount premAccount = new PremiumAccount();
        premAccount.setCustomer(customerService.findByName("John"));
        premAccount.setName();
        premAccount.setDebitCard(new DebitCard((long) 6000));
        premAccount.setCreditCard(new CreditCard((long) 12000));

        accountRepository.create(premAccount);
    }

}
```

My Customer Entity (Short version):

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customer")
    //@JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    @Nullable
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Account> Accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    //private Address Address;


    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName,  List<Account> accounts) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.Accounts = accounts;
    }
```

And my repo:

```
@Repository("customerRepository")
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    @NotNull
    public void save(Customer customer) {
        em.persist(customer);
        em.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public Customer findByName(String Name) {
    return em.find(Customer.class, Name);
    }
}
```

What do I miss, or is this a general bug with the hibernate that cant be avoided? I read somewhere that this is a typical bug.

**Full Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.ruruapps.ibank.domain.Customer. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.ruruapps.ibank.domain.Customer. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:157)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.findByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.ruruapps.ibank.service.CustomerServiceImpl.findByName(CustomerServiceImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.findByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.ruruapps.ibank.AccountRepositoryTest.testSaveAccount(AccountRepositoryTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.ruruapps.ibank.domain.Customer. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1135)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.ruruapps.ibank.repository.CustomerRepositoryImpl.findByName(CustomerRepositoryImpl.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.ruruapps.ibank.domain.Customer. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2587)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:991)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
    ... 75 more
```

Customer Service Impl:

```
@Service("customerService")
@Transactional
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public void save(Customer customer) {
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAll() {
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Customer findById(Long id) {
        return customerRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Customer findByName(String Name) {
        return customerRepository.findByName(Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception. Tell us which line it refers to.

Comment: What is the implementation of `customerService.findByName`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is defined as

```
return em.find(Customer.class, Name);
```

`EntityManager.find()` takes the ID of an entity, and returns the entity that has that ID. The ID of Customer is a Long. It's not the name. You need a query to implement `findByName()`.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it by using a normal jpa criteria query and now it works like it should! :)

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem and the cause was that I didn't specify 'Name' as an ID(a primary key) in my model. As a result the parameter I passed as Id was being compared with the system generated Id (hjid) of that Customer object, and ended up not finding the object with that system generated ID (which is long in type). So it is necessary to explicitly specify the desired primary key in the model.